# Proof of the Monotone Convergence Theorem using Nested intervals Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Nested Intervals Theorem: If  $I_{n}=\left [ a_{n},b_{n} \right ]$ and  $I_{1}\supseteq I_{2}\supseteq I_{3}\supseteq ...$ then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}\neq \varnothing$ In addition if $b_{n}-a_{n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$ then  $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}$ consists of a single point

Monotone Convergence  Theorem: If $a_{n}$ is a monotone and bounded sequence of real numbers then $a_{n}$ converges.

How can you prove the second theorem using only the first(WITHOUT using the least upper bound property, the Bolzano Weierstrass etc.)?

Comment: @nick: given a monotone and bounded sequence, can you construct a nested sequence of intervals, so that you could apply the first Theorem?

Comment: Let us assume that $a_n$ is increasing (if not, replace $a_n$ with $-a_n$). Intuitively, $a_n$ should accumulate at the least upper bound of $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. So set $b = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{a_n\}$. Now consider $I_n = [a_n, b]$. What can you conclude about the sequence $\{I_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in the context of the Nested Intervals Theorem?

Comment: @WNY How do you know that b exists?

Comment: Because the hypothesis says "if $a_n$ is monotone and bounded" (so $\{a_n\}$ is bounded).

Comment: Using the LUB property I can prove the second theorem without even using the first. However, I want a prove that doesn't involve LUB, Bolzano Weierstrass, Cauchy sequences converging etc

Comment: All I am using is that for each bounded set (bounded from above) there exists the least upper bound. If you do not explicitly state this, you will end up having to reprove a special case of this (specific to your given problem).

Comment: Really? Is there no other , more direct way, to prove it without using the least upper bound property?

Comment: @nick: If this isn't direct, I am not sure how more direct one can make it. When you find an acceptable answer, please let us know - I'm curious now. I don't want to go into an extended discussion, but LUB is in a sense equivalent to the theorem you're trying to prove :)

Comment: Well, I asked this question so that I can prove the equivalence of all completeness different "forms", that is 1 the LUB property, 2 the NIT, 3 the MCT, 4 the Bolzano Weierstrass and 5 the convergence of every Cauchy sequence. I can show $1\rightarrow 2$ and $1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 1$ All I need is $2\rightarrow 3$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75850/equivalence-of-completeness-axioms-of-real-numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to prove that the Nested Interval Property implies the Monotone Convergence Theorem.  By that I mean that there are ordered fields with the Nested Interval Property that do not satisfy Monotone Convergence.

The examples I can think of involve non-standard models of analysis. For example, let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers, and let $D$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on $I$.  Then the [ultrapower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}/D$ has the nested interval property but does not satisfy Monotone Convergence.

Briefly, one constructs the ultrapower by first considering the product $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, that is, the set of all sequences of reals. Two such sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are *equivalent* modulo $D$ is the set of $i$ such that $u_i=v_i$ is an element of the ultrafilter $D$.  On the ultrapower, one puts a ring structure by defining addition and multiplication coordinatewise modulo $D$. And if $(u_n)/D$ and $(v_n)/D$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}/D$, we say that $(u_n)/D < (v_n)/D$ if the set of $n$ such that $u_n<v_n$ is an element of $D$. It turns out that the ultrapower just defined is a real-closed ordered field. The reals can be embedded in the ultrapower via equivalence classes of constant sequences. The ordering is non-Archimedean, since if $v_n=n$, then $(v_n)/D$ is larger than any $(u_{k,n})/D$, where $u_{k,n}$ is the integer $k$ for all $n$.

---

If in addition to Nested Intervals, we ask that our field have the Archimedean Property, then Nested Intervals does imply Monotone Convergence. Let the sequence $(c_i)$ be say non-decreasing. For any $n$, let $a_n=c_n$. Let $b_1$ be an upper bound for the sequence $(c_i)$, and define $b_n$ as follows. If nothing below $b_{n-1}$ is an upper bound for $(c_i)$, let $b_n=b_{n-1}$. Otherwise, let $b_n=b_{n-1}-2^{k}$, where $k$ is the largest integer (possibly negative) such that $b_{n-1}-2^k$ is an upper bound for $(c_i)$.  From the Nested Interval Property for the sequence of intervals $(a_n,b_n)$, we can deduce the convergence of the sequence $(c_i)$.

**Remark:** There is a fair literature on the subject. A good survey, at least from the non-standard analysis side, can be found [here.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdigitalcommons.calpoly.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1091%26context%3Dmath_fac&ei=m-47T43RBoOZiQKqmZSTDA&usg=AFQjCNGO_Ow7VUqxAMsDDvKKz4WbeiTRLw&sig2=R_A6QEsMjp9EQEaJfXMoYQ)