# Proof that a converging  increasing sequence converges to a number greater than any term of the sequence using Cauchy Criterion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If we have an strictly increasing sequence $a_{n}$ and we have proved that it converges to a number $a$ can we prove that $a_{n}<a\:\:   \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ **without** using the Least Upper Bound Property or the Monotone Convergence Theorem? The Cauchy Criterion (Every Cauchy sequence converges) is the only version of Completeness that can be used.

I encountered this problem while trying to prove that the Cauchy Criterion implies the Least Upper Bound Property using the hints in the second answer here [Equivalence of Completeness Axioms of Real Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75850/equivalence-of-completeness-axioms-of-real-numbers). I have proved that $\{x_n\} $ and $\{y_n\}$ converge to the same limit but I am unable to prove that that limit is $\sup{T}$.

Comment: I assume when you say *increasing* that is to be interpreted as *strictly increasing*? :)

Comment: **Hint**: Assume the sequence $a_1 > a_2 > \cdots > a_n > \cdots$ has a limit $U$. Now suppose for some $m$ that $U \leq a_m$. What can you say about $a_{m+1}$? Hence?

Comment: The term "increasing sequence" is not strong enough, since it may be that $a_n=a$ constantly. You may want strictly increasing.

Comment: I can say that $a_{m+1}>U$ and generaly if $n>m$ then $a_{n}>a_{m}$

Comment: @RagibZaman: This is why I asked for clarification. Some people use *increasing* to mean just that, employing *nondecreasing* to encompass the case you consider and some use *increasing* to mean *nondecreasing*, and say *strictly increasing* when they don't want any of the terms to be equal.

Comment: @nick: Good. Now take $\epsilon = (a_{m+1}-a_m)/2$ for example. Conclusion?

Comment: Done. Thaks cardinal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume the sequence is strictly increasing, since if the sequence is merely increasing there is an obvious counterexample.

---

Suppose there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_N \geq a.$ Let $ \epsilon = a_{N+1} -a > 0.$ Then for all $ n > N$ we have $ |a_n-a| \geq \epsilon$, which contradicts the assumption that $a_n \to a.$ Thus no such $N$ can exist, and $a_n < a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any version of completeness: the desired result holds in any ordered field.

See e.g. Theorem 22 in $\S 2.1$ of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/3100supp.pdf).  It says, in particular, that a weakly increasing sequence in any ordered field converges iff the set of terms has a least upper bound $L$, and if so $L$ is the limit of the sequence.

If you now assume that the sequence is *strictly* increasing, then the least upper bound $L$ cannot be less than or equal to any term of the sequence: if $L \leq x_n$, then $x_{n+1} > x_n \geq L$, contradicting the fact that $L$ is an upper bound for the set of terms of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

As many have pointed out, we need the hypothesis that the sequence is strictly increasing.

Suppose there was some $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_m>a$. Then for $\epsilon=a_m-a$, there is an $N>0$ such that $|a_n-a| < \epsilon$ for all $n>N$. I.e. $-a_m+a<a_n-a<a_m-a$. We deduce that $a_n<a_m$ for all $n>N$. This is a contradiction, since we just proved that all terms after $a_N$(and consequently terms that occur after $a_m$) are smaller than $a_m$, which cannot happen in an increasing sequence.